# mailto не работает для большого количества адресатов

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день!
Есть необходимость создавать письмо с помощью mailto.
С помощью js создаю следующее:

```
window.location.href = 'mailto:p1@mail.ru;p2@mail.ru;здесь много адресов;p300@mail.ru';
```

Если адресатов не много (0-80) все работает (открывается Оутлук).
Eсли же адресатов много (например 300) браузеры никак не реагируют (кроме фаерфокса, он обрезает количество адресатов).

С чем это может быть связано? Как-то можно починить?

Comment: может как то ограничивать количество адресов?

Comment: Ух ты, бесплатные адреса для спам-листов! Где можно посмотреть эту чудесную страничку?

Comment: это приложение внутри компании, каждый сотрудник может найти другого (по каким-то критериям, например по кабинетам) и добавить в список. После из списка создать письмо.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего причина в превышении максимальной длины url - https://github.com/dreikanter/paradigm.ru/blob/master/posts/2007-12-19_url-max-length.md

Comment: тогда не понятно почему в Хроме строка длинной 7 тыс символов не работает.

Comment: или ограничение ИЕ накладывается как-то и в Оутлук?

Comment: Разумеется нет, ограничение IE - работает только в IE. Может проблема в самом Outlook. 
https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-5459affd-403f-4491-9929-7e9a86b9aaa4
Вот тут пишут что максимальное число получателей ограничено.